Data Lost after convert .py file (GUI with QT) to .exe
So I am developing an application using QT and Python. Then in the python file I use 3 databases, namely using simple CSV and JSON to store information. Then I use the code below to make sure python can find the directory of the data I use in my program.
def resource_path(self, relative_path):
        """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
        try:
            # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
        except Exception:
            base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

        return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

Then here is an example of using the method in my program.
def save_data_nomor(self):
    # Get input from QLineEdit
    new_number = self.ui.inputNomor.text().strip()

    # Check if input is empty
    if new_number == "":
        print("Number cannot be empty.")
        return

    # Load data from JSON file (if available)
    file_path = self.resource_path('database\\data_nomor.json')
    try:
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
                data_nomor = json.load(file)
        else:
            data_nomor = {"nomor": []}  # If the file doesn't exist, create empty data
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading JSON file: {e}")
        data_nomor = {"nomor": []}

    # Add new location to data (avoid duplicates)
    if new_number not in data_nomor["nomor"]:
        data_nomor["nomor"].append(new_number)

    # Save data to JSON file
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data_nomor, file, indent=4)
        print(f"Number '{new_number}' successfully saved.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error saving JSON file: {e}")
    
    # Clear input after saving
    self.ui.inputNomor.clear()


Then I use this command to convert my file to .exe.
pyinstaller --name SmartTank --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico --add-data "database;database" --add-data "images;images" --add-data "font;font" main.py 
Well the problem arises that I can update the data via the exe file. But I can't find where the file is stored. Then if I close the application and open it again. The previous data is not saved.
Then I used another way, namely converting to .exe but not to a single file with this command:
pyinstaller --name SmartTank --windowed --icon=icon.ico --add-data "database;database" --add-data "images;images" --add-data "font;font" main.py 
When I try to open the application, the application can save data properly and when I close it and then open it again, the data is not lost.
Now the problem arises here, when I convert it to setup using Inno Setup Compiler, the initial problem reappears. When I create an application that I have installed, the application cannot save data. So what is the solution?
I have tried several times to convert to .exe in different ways but it still doesn't work.

When an executable created with the onefile mode is run, its contents are decompressed to a temporary directory, and executed from there. When the program is closed, that directory is deleted (at least, in theory): any change done within that directory is completely lost. Installed programs are also prevented to write in their directories (that's why the Inno Setup approach won't work). User editable content should almost always write data using dedicated folders instead. Consider using QStandardPaths functions to get persistent user-data paths.

@musicamante So i have to change my resource_path method?

No, you have to save the data in a specific directory that is completely different from that of the executable, possibly dynamically retrieved based on user paths provided by the system (that's why I suggested looking into QStandardPaths). Functions implemented as you did with resource_path are based on the application path. You must understand the possible contexts in which program and user data may be stored: program and user paths may coincide in some rare cases, but they generally are and must be very different. Consider what could happen if the same program is run by two users.

I use PROFILE_DIR = join(os.environ["APPDATA"], APP_NAME) for the app's settings and stuff..

If the result of the above is a user path (eg: C:/Users/<user name>/...), then it should be fine, but you must also ensure that the path exists, and eventually create it if it doesn't. (please always use @username when replying, or we don't get notifications)
